# Quando devo usar (, [ ou {?

Tags: ortografia, gramática

Eu sei que quando quero em determinados textos utilizamos () para intercalar uma indicação que possa esclarecer o assunto.

Exemplo:

> Afirma-se (não se prova) que é muito comum o recebimento de propina
>   entre políticos.

Mas qual a diferença entre parêntese '()', colchete '[]' e chaves '{}' na língua portuguesa?

Os três existem? Digo, é correto utilizar colchete e chave em português? E quando devo utilizar cada um?

Comment: Não tenho bem a certeza, também gostava de saber mais sobre que situações se usam parênteses rectos ou 'chavetas' em linguagem corrente, mas parece me que estes dois últimos não têm uma 'utilização oficial' bem definida. Acho que são mais utilizados em linguagem técnica e a sua aplicação varia muito de área para área. Vejo frequentemente a utilização do parêntese recto por exemplo, para incluir em citações palavras adicionadas por questão de clareza pelo autor mas que não faziam parte da frase citada originalmente, pelo menos no Inglês.

Comment: Sempre tive essa duvida, pois em livros por exemplo as vezes vejo (...) ou [...], mas nunca soube o porque de ser diferente, já no caso das chaves eu não lembro de ter visto, dai não sei nem se seu uso é correto

Comment: Pois, chavetas também nunca vi com uma utilização consistente. Nesse caso o `[...]`penso que queira dizer que mais uma vez foram adicionados pelo autor (possivelmente para indicar que o texto está cortado ou incompleto), por oposição a fazerem parte do próprio texto transcrito ou citado

Comment: Na matemática { [ ( ) ] }; na computação o livro vai trazer uma indicação de uso geralmente baseado na linguagem de programação ou no modelo computacional; {} chaves são usadas geralmente para expressar conjuntos de coisas {"banana", "maçã"}, ( ) parênteses para explicações ou nomes de numerais por extenso 1 (um); [] colchetes pode ser usado para indicar campos em formulários ou palavras chave.

Comment: Como na grandessíssima maioria das vezes usamos mais os parênteses do que os colchetes ou mesmo as chaves (as quais eu nunca vi num texto convencional), particularmente eu me valho da máxima de que, se não cabe como [aposto](http://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/sint/sint22.php), cabe o uso dos parênteses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **1 -  Parêntese** [(Artigo da Wikipédia, 27-7-2016):](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Par%C3%AAntese)

> Um **parêntese** ou **parêntesis** [nota 1 omitida] (do grego παρένθεσις, "inserção") são utilizados para interpor uma palavra, expressão ou frase num texto para adicionar informação, normalmente explicativa, mas não essencial. A característica fundamental dos parênteses é não afetar a estrutura sintática do período em que é inserido.
>
> Por extensão de sentido, são chamados parênteses os sinais gráficos — "**(**" [abre] e "**)**" [fecha] — que delimitam esses elementos aditivos no discurso.
>
> Usam-se **( )** para isolar palavras, locuções ou frases intercaladas no período, com caráter explicativo, as quais são proferidas em tom mais baixo:
>
> - "Finjamos, pois (o que até fingido e imaginado faz horror), finjamos que vem a Bahia e o resto do Brasil a mãos dos holandeses..." (Vieira)
>
> Também entre parênteses devem ser postos bibliografias, nomes de autores, obras, capítulos, etc., relativos a citações feitas, como foi feito ao final do exemplo acima.
>
> Os **parênteses** são usados no caso de parte independente de uma sentença ou parágrafo, não diretamente relacionada com o restante da oração:
>
> 1. Os profissionais liberais (advogados, médicos, dentistas, engenheiros), quando exercem a profissão por conta própria, são considerados segurados autônomos.
>
> São usados para incluir quantias ou números já expostos por extenso:
>
> 1. Trezentos mil reais (R$ 300.000,00).
>
> São usados também em caso de siglas de estado:
>
> 1. Belo Horizonte (MG)
>
> Obs.: Esses parênteses podem ser substituídos pela barra diagonal:
>
> 1. Belo Horizonte/MG

### **2 -  Colchete** [(Artigo da Wikipédia, 27-7-2016):](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colchete_(s%C3%ADmbolo))

### Colchete, ou *parêntese reto*, têm a mesma finalidade que o parêntese; todavia, seu uso se restringe aos escritos de cunho didático, filológico, científico.

> Em alguns casos, tem menor precedência do que os parênteses, noutros casos a precedência é igual. Os seus símbolos são os seguintes: "**[**" para abrir e "**]**" para fechar. Pode ser empregado:
>
> Em definições do dicionário, para fazer referência à etimologia da palavra. Por exemplo:
>
> - amor- (ô). [Do lat. amore.] 1. Sentimento que predispõe alguém a desejar o bem de outrem, ou de alguma coisa: amor ao próximo; amor ao patrimônio artístico de sua terra. (Novo Dicionário Aurélio);
>
> para intercalar palavras ou símbolos não pertencentes ao texto. Por exemplo:
>
> - Em Aruba se fala o espanhol, o inglês, o holandês e o papiamento. Aqui estão algumas palavras de papiamento que você, com certeza, vai usar:
>
>   1. Bo ta bon? [Você está bem?]
>   2. Dios ta di Brazil. [Deus é brasileiro.];
>
> para inserir comentários e observações em textos já publicados. Por exemplo:
>
> - Machado de Assis escreveu muitas cartas a Sílvio Dinarte. [pseudônimo de Visconde de Taunay, autor de "Inocência"];
>
> para indicar omissões de partes na transcrição de um texto. Por exemplo:
>
> - "É homem de sessenta anos feitos [...] corpo antes cheio que magro, ameno e risonho" (Machado de Assis).]

### **3 -  Chaves** [(Artigo da Wikipédia, 27-7-2016):](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chave_(pontua%C3%A7%C3%A3o))

### Chave("{" abrir, "}" fechar) é um símbolo da língua portuguesa formado de parêntese. Chaves são sinais gráficos usados para indicar a reunião de diversos itens relacionados que formam um grupo, bem como a reunião das diversas divisões de um assunto.

> Na linguística, as chaves são utilizadas para representar [morfemas](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morfema), isto é, *um fragmento mínimo capaz de expressar significado ou a menor unidade significativa que se pode identificar.*

- Tal como um *esquema* de chaves, veja a imagem:

[image]

*fonte linkada em cada um dos tópicos acima.*

Comment: Esta resposta é um copy & paste dos artigos da Wikipédia, sem o assinalar como tal. Vê [esta discussão no meta](http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/258/good-practice-in-posts-that-just-copy-paste-other-sites).

Comment: Tudo quanto é transcrição palavra por palavra deve ser assinalado como tal com indicação explícita da fonte. Caso contrário é plágio.

Comment: Assinalado como descrito no meta.

Comment: Eduardo, creio que não compreendeste a resposta do meta. Eu editei a parte do "parêntese". A ideia é a seguinte: tudo quanto é citação deve vir marcado com aspas se for uma citação curta ou em bloco destacado (no nosso caso colorido) se for citação longa. A fonte (Wikipédia neste caso) deve vir indicado explicitamente. Incluí a data, porque o artigo da wikipédia pode mudar. Aconselho a fazeres o mesmo nos outros. Uma alternativa é fazeres um print screen da wikipédia e postares.

Comment: Retirei o teu exemplo extra: uma coisa é teres um artigo original teu e incluir uma citação; reproduzires um artigo alheio, e adicionares um bocadinho da tua autoria parece-me duvidoso. Mas se quiseres mesmo incluí-lo, a maneira de o fazer corretamente é entre colchetes, como explicado no artigo sobre colchetes: [Exemplo adicional não incluído na Wikipédia: ....]. Mas isto faz-se normalmente para adendas curtas; para o teu exemplo, parece-me questionável.